# How to restrict mongodb aggregation for a given set

Tags: mongodb

The following query would compute sum of GDP per country.
This query would look through each country.
But lets say I want to modify this algo:

`Find gdp for a given subset of countries {BR, CN and UK} only`

How can this be done in mongodb ?[image]

This picture is credited to youtube video here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8xiA4i4eepE

Comment: Can you post the query you have been running please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to filter by `country` **and** by `sum(GDP)` then add a match stage before grouping. For example:

```
db.world_gdp.aggregate([

  // focus on BR, CN and UK countries ... the subsequent stages in the
  // pipeline will only get docs for these countries
  { $match: { country: { $in: ['BR', 'CN', 'UK'] } } },

  // group by country and sum GDP
  { $group: { _id: "$country", gdp: { $sum: "$gdp"} } },

  // restrict to those countries having sum(GDP) >= 2500
  { $match: { gdp: { $gte: 2500 } } },

  // sort by sum(GDP)
  { $sort: { gdp: -1 } }

])
```

Or, if you are interested in filtering by `country` **instead of** filtering by `sum(GDP)` then try this:

```
db.world_gdp.aggregate([

  // focus on BR, CN and UK countries ... the subsequent stages in the
  // pipeline will only get docs for these countries
  { $match: { country: { $in: ['BR', 'CN', 'UK'] } } },

  // group by country and sum GDP
  { $group: { _id: "$country", gdp: { $sum: "$gdp"} } },

  // sort by sum(GDP)
  { $sort: { gdp: -1 } }

])
```